# Default Paragraph Config Per Content Type

Tags: 8, configuration, paragraphs

We're using a paragraph for the hero/header of our site.  Within the paragraph are a number of different toggles to define various options for the hero.

I'd like to have it so that if the user is creating content in one content-type - the default configuration for the paragraph differs from if they're entering content for another content type.

Can I have create unique configurations of a paragraph type based on the content type it's inserted into?

Comment: TL,DR: No. Workarounds: You can either define different paragraph types and set different default paragraphs per field/content type, or write custom code using [hook_field_widget_paragraphs_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/8.2.x).

Comment: What do you mean by configurations?